# Server-Sent Events with Nginx and uWSGI

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, server-sent-events

Is it possible to use [server-sent events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) from a python/Flask application that is behind uWSGI and Nginx?

I've found packages that implement SSE in python/Flask, but they seem to all do so using gevent and greenlets.

https://github.com/DazWorrall/flask-sse

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of uWSGI (from 1.9) have built-in support for websockets / SSE. This article provides an excellent guide:

[uWSGI docs: Offloading Websockets and Server-Sent Events](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/articles/OffloadingWebsocketsAndSSE.html)

Answer (score 0):

can't you simply use gevent with uWSGI ?

Generally this kind of technologies should be used with async engines as the multithread/multiprocess paradigm would be too much costly.

Comment: i can confirm that it works without problems with uWSGI+gevent